# An exception in a model manytomany field Django

Tags: django, django-models

I need to make a request on the model himself :

```
class Course(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='course', limit_choices_to={'userprofile__status': 'teacher'})

class Assignment (models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='assignment')
    admins = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True, limit_choices_to={'userprofile__status': 'teacher'})
```

I need admin contain all users (with teacher as status) without the owner. I have tried with Q objects but it was not a success...

Comment: Are you looking for `Assignment.objects.filter(admins__isnull=True)`?

Comment: I don't understand, it returns an Assignment, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do this right on the model, but if you could it would be done with `F`. Something like:

```
from django.db.models import Q, F

...

limit_choices_to=Q(userprofile__status='teacher') & ~Q(id=F('owner_id'))
```

You have to use `Q` because you can't assert a negative with the dictionary pattern. The `~` negates the second `Q` and `F('owner_id')` is use to select the value for owner.

Like I said, though, I haven't tried to do this myself, so I can't say if it will work or not. You'll just have to give it a whirl and let us know.

Comment: I am testing, now I havn't got any user, I am trying to change ! (It is `~Q(id=F('owner__id'))` not `~Q(id=F('owner_id'))`)

Comment: In facts, I have simplified the model, because the assignment refers to a course and the course have an owner. So I have tried that : `limit_choices_to=Q(userprofile__status='teacher') & ~Q(id=F('course__owner__id'))` but no.. If I change the F() by an id it is ok

Comment: No. Single underscore. The actual field on the model is `owner_id`. The `owner` attribute is a property whose getter merely pulls the `User` with that id.

Comment: Look my attempt, my response was sent before yours. If I do : limit_choices_to=Q(userprofile__status='teacher') & ~Q(id=F('course__owner_id')) with only one underscore, I have an error with name of real fields...

Comment: I have tried everything, I have not got any object in my list.. I edit my post with my real model architecture.